# MS Access Variable declaration/Overflow issue

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, overflow

I have been working on this issue for my work. I am trying to create a similar function to NetworkDays in Excel. This will return the business days between two dates excluding holidays. This is a code sample that I have retyped and tried to tweak to make it work. The Variable dateInc is a incrementing var. that seems to overflow when ever I try and set the value equal to the startDate number. This startdate would in turn make the dateInc count from the start date to the end date. I am just not sure if this is an amateur mistake or a real issue I need to learn about. I have tried to add error handling to skip the error and resume but it is just all of them. I am open to all constructive criticism and any advice in coding practice and solutions are welcome.

Note: I have tried to accommodate for potential uneven date values with times. Although this did not change anything and my data happens to have no time in the date values.

```
Function Workdays(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim countDays&, dateInc#, startLong#, endLong#, strSQL$
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    'intialize variables to avoid overflow|Note dates are converted to a double
    countDays = 0
    dateInc = 0
    startLong = CDbl(startDate)
    endLong = CDbl(endDate)
    'SQL select statement
    strSQL = "Select holDate from Holidays"
    'Open database using SQL
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    'set the date comparison to the start date's number format
    dateInc = startLong
    Do Until dateInc = endLong

        Select Case Weekday(CDate(dateInc))
            Case vbSaturday
            'Nothing happens
            Case vbSunday
            'Nothing happens

            Case Else
                rs.FindFirst ("holDate = # " & Format(CDate(dateInc), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
                If rs.NoMatch = True Then
                    countDays = countDays + 1
                    End If
        End Select
        dateInc = dateInc + 1
    Loop
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    dateInc = 0
    Workdays = countDays
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring your variables as Double in the beginning?

Comment: @Benno Grimm Yes I have tried a long and double. and it has made no difference. The dateInc number seems to always get incremented or somehow set to the max value.

Comment: I am really not sure why this is happening, but if you know the line where the overflow occurs, user MsgBoxes to check the value of variables (all of them) and there current datatype (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s4zz68xc.aspx)..  Maybe trouble-shooting will help you here

Comment: The type name is useful I will try it out, thank you!

Comment: Hope you can find the error (if so, consider posting an answer for future users with the same problem ;) )

Answer (score 0):

It works! I tried this at home and it worked perfectly.......Idk what I did wrong.